# Mount Shares Permanently - mount:cifs Permission Denied

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, samba, cifs

I have two machines running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The first is a home server which is used for network attached storage using SMB. The second is a desktop, for which I want to create a permanent mount to the network attached storage.

I can connect to the network share using the Ubuntu GUI (below):
[image: Ubuntu Network Authentication]

The problem with this approach is that some applications fail to write to the storage when it's mounted that way. Apparently I need to create a permanent mount point so that it's always mounted and authenticated.

I've been following this tutorial about how to do it
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

**Steps Taken**

Install cifs and setup mount point...

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
sudo mkdir /media/storage
```

Create credentials file `~/.smbcredentials`...

```
gedit ~/.smbcredentials
```

Contents...

```
username=MY_SERVER_USERNAME
password=MY_SERVER_PASSWORD
domain=SERVER
```

Permissions...

```
chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials
```

**Note:** I actually never know what **domain** refers to, do I just use "SERVER", which is the name of the machine, and that seems to work, but I haven't got the foggiest idea whether or not that's right.

Create entry in `/etc/fstab`...

```
//SERVER/storage /media/storage cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

At this point, I have my credentials set up, I have an entry in fstab, and Ubuntu recognises the share, but when I try to access it, I get this:

> mount:cifs Permission Denied

No useful reason why I can't get access.

**What I've Tried**

Apparently SMB doesn't support `sec=ntlm` anymore? So changing the entry in `/etc/fstab/` to this ***almost*** works:

```
//SERVER/storage /media/storage cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nofail 0 0
```

Now I can access the share, but I only have read access.

**Questions**

- How do I set up my permanent mount to the network share so that I have full read/write access?
- If `sec=ntlm` no longer works, how do I find out what `sec=` should be?
- What *should* the `domain` entry in my credentials file be?

Comment: DOMAIN is the name of the workgroup. Is required for Windows. If you log into a domain on windows your login is domain/user with a password. That is what is asked here. "Apparently SMB doesn't support sec=ntlm anymore? " correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using v22.04 (and for that matter 20.04) I have set up an SMB share in fstab to access my Synology video NAS share with the following command which works faultlessly:

```
//192.168.1.117/video /media/NAS/video cifs username=[user],password=[password],rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

Of course, replace the credentials in square brackets with your own and the ip address to your NAS as well as the uid and gid with values that are appropriate for your user... (and further, if it works, restore the credentials file to the line in fstab to preserve security).

Maybe try first without the smbcreditials file as in the example above then add in the credentials file to fstab if that works (to replace the open username and password credentials to fine tune your entries.
The other steps already taken creating the mountpoint appear correct.

I would suggest, if keeping the smb credentials open works, then initially copy the validated line after which simply commenting out (#) the line with the open to view creds, then remove the line when the smb credentials file is resolved in order to preserve what you have done.

Comment: Also replace the *uid* and *gid* in the fstab line with values that are appropriate for your user.

Comment: @OrganicMarble are the _uid_ and _gid_ values for the user on the server, or the user on the desktop?

Comment: @MatthewLayton do not follow this method. Use a credintials file. Exposing a password is bad even if it works ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for reminding me.. I had intended to include that but forgotten it until your timely reminder. Now updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I just deleted "sec=ntlm" and "domain=xxx" and now access to our NAS works.  Also didn't use uid or gid...